# R - Use TileMaker in Shiny Apps

Tags: r, dashboard, shiny

I'd like to add some TileMaker elements in my shiny apps to make it a better dashboard (but I did not use *shinydashboard* structure). See the server.R and ui.R below for minimal example:

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(TileMaker)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

Tilemaker<-renderPlot({

  Button1 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 2,Value = 3.57,Subtitle = "Times apple eaten")
  Button2 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 3,Value = 13.7,Subtitle = "Nutritional value")
  Button3 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 4,Value = 1,Subtitle = "Yumminess factor")
  Button4 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 5,Size=1,Value = 5,Subtitle = "Inconsistencies")
  Div1 <- DivMaker(Title = "Quantativity factors",Buttons = paste(Button1,Button2))
  Div2 <- DivMaker(Title = "Implementation procedures",Buttons = paste(Button3,Button4))
  TileMaker(MainTitle = "Hello",Divs = paste(Div1,Div2), FileName = "123.html")
  browseURL("123.html")
 })  
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
mainPanel(
      navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Tilemaker",h1("Tilemaker"),plotOutput(Tilemaker))
   )
  )
 ) 
)
```

I've searched for a while but no related discussion and I tried both *renderplot* and *renderimage* but both did not work. Is TilmeMaker another render type or it cannot be used in shiny app? Any advise is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `renderUI`( if you want to create Tile on server side) and not need to save (as said in help

> "If you would like just HTML code (suitable for inserting in a
>   dashboard or another document, you can use the Divs"

)

## Example

```
library(shiny)
library(TileMaker)
server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$Tilemaker<-renderUI({

    Button1 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 2,Value = 3.57,Subtitle = "Times apple eaten")
    Button2 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 3,Value = 13.7,Subtitle = "Nutritional value")
    Button3 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 4,Value = 1,Subtitle = "Yumminess factor")
    Button4 <- ButtonMaker(Color = 5,Size=1,Value = 5,Subtitle = "Inconsistencies")
    Div1 <- DivMaker(Title = "Quantativity factors",Buttons = paste(Button1,Button2))
    Div2 <- DivMaker(Title = "Implementation procedures",Buttons = paste(Button3,Button4))
    return( list(h1("Hello"),HTML(Div1,Div2)))
  })  
})

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    navlistPanel(
      tabPanel("Tilemaker",h1("Tilemaker"),uiOutput("Tilemaker"))
    )
  )
) 
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: The code above solved the problem perfectly and now Tilemaker and shiny are greatly integrated.